# Not able to run Talend job in Yarn cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, talend

I am using TOS 7.1 with MapR 6.0 distribution and sprak2.2.

Flow :
Master job -> BigData Spark job1 [yarn mode: client]
Master job -> BigData spark job2 [yarn mode: cluster]

Both job1 & job2 are same, just yarn deploy mode is different. Job with "client" mode is working fine when executed from Linux edge node, but "cluster" mode from same parent job is not running.

Below is error from yarn-application log for cluster mode:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: routines/system/api/TalendJob.

from error & other online help for this, it looks evident some libraries is not getting exported during build. But, had that been the case, jobs should not run in even "client" mode.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talend creates a routines.jar in ../lib/ directory. This routines.jar provides mandatory definition to interface required for calling spark driver program , And spark driver context is not able to find this jar from Edge node wherein Talend is called.

Simple solution is pass this jar as additional required yarn archive jar, along with any other if required.
I have bundled this jar with other required hive/zookeeper required jar and move to hdfs. ANd this hdfs path is provided as additional spark property for Yarn Archive jars.